# foreach() error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

i keep getting this error for an array of errors that i have set in a method

here is the code

```
public function showerrors() {
        echo "<h3> ERRORS!!</h3>";
        foreach ($this->errors as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
```

i keep getting this "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when i run the program
i set the errors array in the constructor like this

```
 $this->errors = array();
```

so im not entirely sure why it wont print the errors!

```
public function validdata() {
        if (!isset($this->email)) {
            $this->errors[] = "email address is empty and is a required field";
        }

        if ($this->password1 !== $this->password2) {
            $this->errors[] = "passwords are not equal ";
        }
        if (!isset($this->password1) || !isset($this->password2)) {
            $this->errors[] = "password fields cannot be empty ";
        }
        if (!isset($this->firstname)) {
            $this->errors[] = "firstname field is empty and is a required field";
        }
        if (!isset($this->secondname)) {
            $this->errors[] = "second name field is empty and is a required field";
        }

        if (!isset($this->city)) {
            $this->errors[] = "city field is empty and is a required field";
        }


        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

here is how i add data to the array itself! thanks for the help also!

alright i added this to the method

```
public function showerrors() {
        echo "<h3> ERRORS!!</h3>";
        echo "<p>" . var_dump($this->errors) . "</p>";
        foreach ($this->errors as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value;
        }
```

then it outputs on my page  this

ERRORS!!
string(20) "invalid submission!!"  if i type nothing into my text boxes so its saying its a string??

here is my constructor also, soory about this im new to php!

```
  public function __construct() {

        $this->submit  = isset($_GET['submit'])? 1 : 0;
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->firstname = $this->filter($_GET['firstname']);
        $this->secondname = $this->filter($_GET['surname']);
        $this->email = $this->filter($_GET['email']);
        $this->password1 = $this->filter($_GET['password']);
        $this->password2 = $this->filter($_GET['renter']);
        $this->address1 = $this->filter($_GET['address1']);
        $this->address2 = $this->filter($_GET['address2']);

        $this->city = $this->filter($_GET['city']);
        $this->country = $this->filter($_GET['country']);
        $this->postcode = $this->filter($_GET['postcode']);


        $this->token = $_GET['token'];
    }
```

Comment: Post more code.  My bet is that somewhere you are attempting to add to `$this->errors` but accidentally used the `=` instead of `[] =` and ended up overwriting it with a scalar...

Comment: A common mistake that I sometimes do myself when I type too fast is `$this->errors = 'foo';` instead of `$this->errors[] = 'foo';`. As far as this code goes, it's not the problem.

Comment: Check with var_dump for what happened before the foreach.

Comment: `$this->errors` may be an array initially, but it certainly isn’t one when `showerrors` is called. So why don’t you just dump its value in `showerrors` to see what it is?

Comment: No problem with the newly posted code either.  Look for any other use of `$this->errors`, and post the constructor too.

Comment: @eoin No, go find the method that sets the string `"invalid submission"`. That's where your error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your default (nothing filled in) validation to your form, where the message `"invalid submission"` is set, you left out brackets `[]`, causing `$this->errors` to be overwritten with a plain string rather than appending to the array.

```
// Change
$this->errors = "invalid submission";

//...to...
$this->errors[] = "invalid submission";
```